# Executing PostgreSQL function in informatica

Tags: sql, transformation, informatica

I'm using informatica desinger and postgres DB and i'm trying to execute a sql function that i created in sql. I tried to connect them with "sql transform" but i get the following error:

"invalid function agruments", but since I use constants I'm positive that i got them on the right order (i ran the function successfully in postgres)

Help? please...

Comment: What does the postgres logfile say, does the query ever reach the DBMS?

Answer (score 0):

there could be the error with the comments passed in transformation. You need to make sure function name mentioned is correctly spelled.